# What are the cross-chain names for the lowest and principal coin denominations?

Tags: blockchain, ether, bitcoin

For example:

- In Ethereum WEI is the lowest denominator, ETH is the principal one.
- In Bitcoin SAT is the lowest denominator, BTC is the principal one.

**What would be the chain-independant technical terms for the 'lowest denomination' and 'principal denomination'?**

I'm looking for one word that would mean both 'WEI' and 'SAT', and another word which would mean both 'ETH' and 'BTC'.

If there aren't such words, why is it so?

---

I've searched around for the universal denomination names but all I can see are specific names, such as: [1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/574/112840) [2](https://www.gemini.com/cryptopedia/satoshi-value-gwei-to-ether-to-wei-converter-eth-gwei)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one word that would mean both 'WEI' and 'SAT', because the denominations for ETH and BTC are different. One ETH equals 10^18 WEI, and one BTC equals 100^6 SAT. Another word which would mean, for example, both 'ETH' and 'BTC', could be `COIN` because both of them have their native blockchain networks.