# What are Wei, Gwei and other Ether multipliers

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, math, wei

So, when someone sends you 1 Wei, are they sending you the constant "Wei", or 1e-18 Ether? Like what I'm asking is that, Ether, Wei or Gwei, they are constant values, but they are not convertible, like they are unique values, just that some front end interfaces make it seem like all these constants are interchangeable?

Comment: They are just numbers. When we say a wallet has a 10 **18 balance, we automatically know that this is 1 ether. This is not different from how see cents and dollars.

Comment: [You can find standard Ethereum multipliers here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/574/620). Yes they are constant, same as kilo, mega, giga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wei, Gwei are better understood as smaller denominations or units of Ether. Just like 100 cents make up a dollar, 10^18 wei make up one Ether and similarly 10^9 gwei (giga-wei) also make up an ether.

These units help denominate smaller ether amounts and gas prices in a human-readable format. You can read more about these denominations and ether on [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/intro-to-ether/#denominations).